# Generating html link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I have a simple javascript question (I'm not a javascript expert, so excuse me for this simple question ;). 
We are currently migrating a system and on the old system there should be a simple HTML-link which directs you to the new system (with the same path). My current approach doesn't not work really well:

```
Information can be found<a href="javascript:'('http://theNewServername:8080/'+(window.location.pathname));">here </a>
```

This doesn't represent me the right href-link. Can you help me with this 'one-liner'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
<a href="javascript:void(window.location.href='http://theNewServername:8080/'+(window.location.hostname))">here </a>
```

Comment: I imagine Op probably wants *window.location.pathname* though ... no?

Comment: I just corrected what I saw... the pathname on the new server is the hostname of the current one.

Comment: yes, right. I wanted pathname. I edited it above. It works :-) Thanks :)